# replacing %namn% in php

Tags: php, html, replace, textfield

i want to replace the %namn% with something i put in a textfield. example:

i'm typing in Josh in a textfield, i want the %namn% to be Josh and so on.
i have static stuff that are meant to be random as you can see down there: `$first`, `$second` and `$third`.

> Bongo tycker att %namn% är ett fint namn! Bongo hade gärna känt %namn% och bjudit %namn% på bananer! Bananer är gott tycker Bongo! Bongo tycker att $stad är fint

converted to:

> Bongo tycker att Josh är ett fint namn! Bongo hade gärna känt Josh och bjudit Josh på bananer! Bananer är gott tycker Bongo! Bongo tycker att stad är fint

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<?php
$first = 'Bongo tycker att %namn% är ett fint namn! Bongo hade gärna känt %namn% och bjudit %namn% på bananer! Bananer är gott tycker Bongo! Bongo tycker att stad är fint';
$second = 'Bongo Vet att %namn% vill ha en sak! om Bongo hade kunnat så Hade Bongo gett %namn% en Banansak! Bongo tycker att %namn% presterade bra i skolan! %namn% är BÄST!';
$third = 'Bongo ÄLSKAR %namn%s musiksmak! Bongo hade gärna delat en banan samtidigt som Dem lyssnade på musik ihop! %namn%s motto stämmer helt och hållet med Bongos!';
$array = array($first, $second, $third);
echo $array[array_rand($array)];
?>
```

Comment: i don't undersdtand which part is meant to be random.
But to replace `%namn%` with the users input , have a look at the [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) method in PHP

Comment: Yeah, i've tried str_replace, but it only barks at me when i do what i think is right. I dont get it to work, especially if i use str_replace with a textfield string too..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/de/function.str-replace.php) function of php:

```
$first = 'Bongo tycker att %namn% är ett fint namn! Bongo hade gärna känt %namn% och bjudit %namn% på bananer! Bananer är gott tycker Bongo! Bongo tycker att stad är fint';
echo str_replace('%namn%', 'Conny', $first);
```

Or if that is not working for you, you can also use [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/de/function.sprintf.php):

```
$first = 'Bongo tycker att %1$s är ett fint namn! Bongo hade gärna känt %1$s och bjudit %1$s på bananer! Bananer är gott tycker Bongo! Bongo tycker att stad är fint';
echo sprintf($first, 'Conny');
```

Both are working for me.

Update:
not quite sure if I understood you correctly. You want to randomly select one of the three strings and then replace the name in that string?

```
$first = 'Bongo tycker att %namn% är ett fint namn! Bongo hade gärna känt    %namn% och bjudit %namn% på bananer! Bananer är gott tycker Bongo! Bongo tycker att stad är fint';
$second = 'Bongo Vet att %namn% vill ha en sak! om Bongo hade kunnat så Hade Bongo gett %namn% en Banansak! Bongo tycker att %namn% presterade bra i skolan! %namn% är BÄST!';
$third = 'Bongo ÄLSKAR %namn%s musiksmak! Bongo hade gärna delat en banan samtidigt som Dem lyssnade på musik ihop! %namn%s motto stämmer helt och hållet med Bongos!';
$array = array($first, $second, $third);
echo str_replace('%namn%', 'Josh', $array[array_rand($array)]);
```

Update:
ok :), first read this tutorial: [HTML Forms](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp).
You can access the submitted variables via the $_POST variable. Try this:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['name']))
    {
        $name = $_POST['name'];

        $first = 'Bongo tycker att %namn% är ett fint namn! Bongo hade gärna känt    %namn% och bjudit %namn% på bananer! Bananer är gott tycker Bongo! Bongo tycker att stad är fint';
        $second = 'Bongo Vet att %namn% vill ha en sak! om Bongo hade kunnat så Hade Bongo gett %namn% en Banansak! Bongo tycker att %namn% presterade bra i skolan! %namn% är BÄST!';
        $third = 'Bongo ÄLSKAR %namn%s musiksmak! Bongo hade gärna delat en banan samtidigt som Dem lyssnade på musik ihop! %namn%s motto stämmer helt och hållet med Bongos!';
        $array = array($first, $second, $third);
        echo str_replace('%namn%', $name, $array[array_rand($array)]);
    }
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" value="" name="name" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

You can also put the php-code into a seperate .php-File and define in the action-attribute of the form-element. E.g. the php-file is called replace.php:

```
<form action="replace.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" value="" name="name" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

hope that helps ^^

Comment: Will this use the random array then?  $ first , $second and $third is the three variables that are used randomly in the array. Without replacing %name% i get it to randomize it. But will this also randomize? :) thanks for the answer btw!

Comment: basically i want to have a textbox on a page, where i fill in names, for an example Josh, when i then press a button i get one of the variables echoed/printed in basic html with % namn% replaced with what i wrote in the textbox. So, if i type josh in the box, it will print out " Bongo tycker att Josh /../ " or one of the others :) i dont know if i can explain it any better :(

Comment: do you have a html form-element? How do you submit the name you write in the textbox?

Comment: I have not yet completed that. Im not sure how to make all this to work together.  I can make a simple html form, but i dont really know how to make this script to handle that input at the same time it generates a random output ant replaces the % namn%. My brain will soon explode lol

Comment: @conny I added an example.

Comment: Thank you very very much! You're my hero :D now im only going to make a nice theme for this and in the future when im more sure about coding, ill make this aJax :D

Comment: awesome^^, ajax is fun :)